# How can we show that the multi-polylogarithmic function $L_{\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_n}(z)=\frac{1}{n!}(L_1(z))^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, logarithms, polylogarithm

How can we show that the multi-polylogarithmic function
$$L_{\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_n}(z)=\frac{1}{n!}(L_1(z))^n.$$
Here $L_1(z)=-log(1-z)$.

I know that $\frac{d}{dz}L_{k_1,\ldots,k_r}(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}L_{k_1,\ldots,k_{r-1}}(z)$
for $k_r=1$. Please help me with this.

Comment: Which definition do you use? [This one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultidimensionalPolylogarithm.html)? (Would you include it in the question?)

Comment: @metamorphy Yes

Comment: @metamorphy No, I haven't included the definition in my question. Also, I made a mistake. I amended it.

Comment: You have already pointed out the "workhorse" identity to use. It remains simply to use induction and $$\frac{d}{dz}\log^n(1-z)=-\frac{n}{1-z}\log^{n-1}(1-z).$$